# TCPDF consuming the Memory & It is not freeing up memory

Tags: php, cakephp, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF library to generate report on one of my application. When ever i generate PDF using TCPDF, chunk of memory get allocated like  256MB & after generating the PDF, that allocated memory is not getting free.

This is blocking around 2GB memory. So the final solution which i have is change the TCPDF lib with other lib.

Can anybody knows why TCPDF allocates the memory or is there any way to flush the memory after the pdf generation?

Comment: Is there a question here that you want answering?

Comment: Yes, wanted to know the reason why TCPDF eats up the memory & that memory is not getting free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you cleaning your output buffer in your View? I am also using TCPDF in some of my Cake projects, but never had this problem. Your view should have somthing like this:

```
<?php
// Start output buffering
ob_start();

// Your TCPDF code here

// Clean the output buffer
ob_end_clean();
```

Works just fine for me, memory is freed right after generation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have PHP5 running on your server: does your TCPDF object have a `__deconstruct()` method?

If you have PHP4 running on your server: try `unset($pdfobject)`.

Run these methods once you're done creating/writing/printing your PDF.